# Retrieving a Single Row SSIS Result Set with More than 8000 Characters

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm validating headers on a file before import, and part of that involves retrieving the headers of the import table in a single string, separated by commas. The single string result is roughly 9000 characters.

In SSIS, I was getting an error when bringing back the result set as *varchar(MAX)*, but *varchar(8000)* doesn't provide the full result. The *varchar(MAX)* error I was getting is similar to the error you would get if you were trying to return a *full result set* but had told SSIS that it was a *single row*.

Do I have any options here that don't involve splitting the result set or only checking 8000 characters?

**Less Desirable Solution:** I ended up splitting my query in two, one for the first 8000 and the second for SUBSTRING(x,8001,x-8000). It's not as elegant as I wanted it to be, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting my query in two, one for the first 8000 and the second for SUBSTRING(x,8001,x-8000). It's not as elegant as I wanted it to be, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype of the column to DT_NTEXT (if you expect unicode characters) or DT_TEXT (if you expect no unicode characters). These data types can be inserted into nvarchar(max) and varchar(max) fields in SQL.

Comment: I don't need to insert into a *MAX* field. I need to put the result of a SQL Server query into an SSIS variable so that I can use that variable to validate my headers. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Ok. Even if you don't need to insert into a (MAX) field, DT_TEXT and DT_NTEXT will get you around the 8k/4k limit of DT_STR and DT_WSTR.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old-school "break Microsoft tools to make them work properly" solution to this. It's the classic "bung it into an object and parse out" solution.

You need an extra System.Object variable set up in Variables (I'll call this oResult)
The string result you want to create and export out of a task we'll call sResult.

Build your string in a script/Execute SQL task, set the result set to Full Result Set. Then put oResult in as the first (number 0) output for the task in the "Result Set" tab.

In your execute task body, set your internal variable containing the result as an NVARCHAR(MAX). Then SELECT this variable as you would do normally to send the data to the output result set.

What happens is a get-around which Microsoft left in for clients who need to be able to play around with large volumes of informational (non-programmatic) text and who would otherwise not be able to use SSIS. Because it's exporting to an object (i.e. a table in a system.object), the string can be any length you like. All that remains is for you to get the value back out again.

Set up a ForEach loop container, set the enumerator to ADO Enumerator, and the ADO source object variable to oResult. This means the enumerator is now reading the 1-row table you created above. Under "Variable Mappings", set sResult to index 0 (the first column value).

This assignment bypasses the crazy 8000 character limit, which means you can now import sResult into another task and cast it as NVARCHAR(MAX).

Hey Presto! It's not pretty but it works, and AFAICT it doesn't use depreciated features.